# Activity indicator/bar in Python

Tags: python

I have one task/command in Python which takes quite a long time. I would like to show some activity indicator or progress bar while this command is running. I cannot use traditional progress bar libraries because I cannot iterate in loop, since it is just one command.

I understand that progress bar would be quite difficult to implement because I don't know how long this command will run. I was thinking about some activity indicator, like spinning bar or something.

Any ideas how to implement it?

Comment: Does your program have GUI? What's the command you're using? Did you write it yourself or does it depend on any 3rd party tools?

Comment: Have you looked at the question [_Python: Run a progess bar and work simultaneously?_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13547921/python-run-a-progess-bar-and-work-simultaneously/13551119#13551119)

Comment: It does not have GUI, it is cli. I am using Python-requests library to connect to http api which then runs some tasks on remote node and then returns http status code. That is it. I am not downloading any file, so there is no way for me to check download progress. All I can do is wait until remote http returns status code. But I would like to improve user's experience and show at least some activity indicator.

Comment: @martineau thanks a lot! That works like a charm!

Comment: Tom: Good to hear. Please consider up-voting whichever of the answers to the question you used.